# Daphne ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, daphne

I'm unable to get the Daphne server running.  It always fails with the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/bin/daphne", line 8, in <module>
     sys.exit(CommandLineInterface.entrypoint())
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/daphne/cli.py", line 171, in entrypoint
     cls().run(sys.argv[1:])
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/daphne/cli.py", line 233, in run
     application = import_by_path(args.application)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/daphne/utils.py", line 12, in import_by_path
     target = importlib.import_module(module_path)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apps'
```

/home/prassel/apps/asgi.py

```
django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http": django_asgi_app,
        "websocket": URLRouter([path('ws/notifications/', NotificationConsumer.as_asgi())]),
    }
)
```

I'm starting Daphne as follows from /home/prassel/docker-compose.yml

```
  daphne:
    platform: linux/amd64
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.daphne
    command: 'sh -c "daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000  apps.asgi:application"'
    restart: always
    working_dir: /home/prassel
```

Dockerfile.daphne

```
FROM python:3.8-buster

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

ARG REQUIREMENTS_FILE

WORKDIR /home/prassel/

RUN pip install daphne
```

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` file inside `apps` folder?

Comment: Yes, I have. This is the content 
default_app_config = "apps.trainingtelemetry.apps.TrainingTelemetryConfig" 

There are other folders as well.

Comment: Can you post a full taceback? (output before the error)

Comment: Please, edit your question instead. SO comments have limited support for formatting

Comment: I have updated the description with complete traceback

Comment: Are you sure, you're running the `daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000  apps.asgi:application` command from your project folder? (`/home/prassel/sml-266/simlai-api/`)

Comment: I have updated the description on how I'm starting Daphne

Comment: If my answer didn't help, please, post contents of your `Dockerfile.daphne`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** You're not adding your project files to your Docker container during the build, so your container doesn't have anything to run. You need to add them using a `COPY` or an `ADD` command.

It's one of the basics of Docker. You should do some reading on what are Docker containers and how they work, or you can use an [official example](https://github.com/docker/awesome-compose/blob/master/django/app/Dockerfile) or follow one of a countless
Django + Docker tutorials available on the web.

---

I believe the issue lies within your Docker setup. Make sure you set `WORKDIR` in your `Dockerfile.daphne` and `working_dir:` in your `docker-compose.yml` to the same value, and you should be good.

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ...

WORKDIR /yourproject

COPY ...

RUN ...

...

...
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
  daphne:
    platform: linux/amd64
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.daphne
    command: 'sh -c "daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8000  apps.asgi:application"'
    restart: always
    working_dir: /yourproject
```

Comment: @SelvaPrasad can you add your Dockerfile to the question. Or upload a minimal reproduction repo to GitHub? Everything should really work at this point. Also, make sure that you're running `docker compose build` after making changes to Dockerfiles

Comment: I have added the Dockerfile contents.   I will run docker compose build

Comment: Can you please tell me if I'm using the module name correctly?  What is the asgi name that I need  to pass on to Daphne? Is the name apps.asgi:application correct? I'm suspecting that I'm mixing it up there.

Comment: @SelvaPrasad updated my answer. Your module name is correct. Your Dockerfile is really off. You need to read up on Docker or try working without it and add it later when you need it